# Specific Youtube Clips don't embed with Youtube Chromeless

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm having some issues with Youtube clip embedding using the chromeless jQuery plugin.
http://www.viget.com/inspire/youtube-chromeless-video-jquery-plugin/

Most of the videos I embed work fine, but there is a specific 2 videos which refuse to embed.

I have setup a test page which has a working video and the 2 broken videos, on the same page.
(Link no longer valid)

The videos which do not work are .mov files before being uploaded and both came from the same producer.

I assume that this is an encoding related bug, but thats just my guess.
Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: They work for me.  Sounds like just a delay in the encoding?

Comment: The test link doesn't work as of February 7, 2012.

Comment: Just to clear this up.
This issue was youtube had flagged the video as a copyright violation (even though the video still plays on youtube.com itself).
The video had a stock audio track used in it, which was legitimately aquired. After resolving this dispute the video worked.